# Android URL - Caminho incompleto

Tags: android, url

Olá!

Estou tentando criar uma `URL` mas parece que quando eu crio a `URL` ela não é criada com o caminho completo.

Criação da URL

```
url = new URL("https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/" + authID + "/Message/");
```

Quando eu pego o caminho da URL

```
System.out.println(url.getPath());
```

O resultado é: `I/System.out: /v1/Account/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Message/`

Alguém sabe como resolver isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala GuiDupas,

Por que você está pegando o getPath()?

Você pode reparar que se printar só a url já resolve:

```
System.out.println(url);
```

Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo.